# How to get real eigenvectors and eigenvalues using Python numpy library?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am using `numpy` python library to calculate `eigenvalues` and `eigenvectors` of a asymmetric matrix. The eigenvalues i am getting are complex values and corresponding eigenvectors also consist of complex values. Is there any possible way to get `real eigenvalues` and eigenvectors from numpy library ?

Comment: What makes you think you are supposed to get *real* eigenvalues of an *asymmetric* matrix?

Comment: @OliverW. OP probably means the real representation of the spectral decomposition.